# Run-time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)': Automation Error

Tags: excel, vba

My code is running perfectly until get to "If c = "" Then". At this point the run time error  **'-2147418113 (8000ffff)': Automation Error** is raised. I have put an On Error Resume Next statement to check if everything goes right if I skip this line and it does.  I really don't understand what this error means and I wasn't able to find useful information about it. Could someone bring light to this problem? I have tried to change **"If c = "" Then" to "If len(c.value)=0 Then"** but it raises the same error. All the variables in AddresRawDataFile are defined as public (as range) and they were set to range in a different module, called PublicVariable, which is called by every procedure.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Ok_Click()

    Dim MsgAlert As String
    Dim MsgBoxAlert As Variant 'Message box for for many checks done below
    Dim c As Variant 'Variable used in a for each structure
    Dim AddressRawDataFile As Variant 'Array of variables with address in Box2_UPb_Options

    'Code to assign values from Box2_UPb_Options to the related variables

    AddressRawDataFile = Array(RawHg202Range, RawPb204Range, RawPb206Range, RawPb207Range, RawPb208Range, RawTh232Range, RawU238Range, _
    RawHg202Header, RawPb204HeaderRange, RawPb206HeaderRange, RawPb207HeaderRange, RawPb208HeaderRange, RawTh232HeaderRange, _
    RawU238HeaderRange)


    'All of the above variables must not be = ""
    For Each c In AddressRawDataFile
        'On Error Resume Next
        If c = "" Then
            MsgBoxAlert = MsgBox("There are one or more addresses missing in Start-AND-Options sheet. " & _
            "Please, check it.", vbOKOnly, "Missing Address")
                Load Box2_UPb_Options
                    Box2_UPb_Options.MultiPage1.Value = 2
                        Box2_UPb_Options.Show
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I've run your code (Excel 2010) and I'm not getting an error at that line. Perhaps I'm missing something... If you put a breakpoint at that line and inspect `c` in a watch, what does it contain?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 too. Look, I am not sure if I've understood your question, but let me try answer it. The variable c actually is not something special, I've just created it to use in the "For Each" structure. I use it to check if any of the cells, represented by the variables in AddressRawDataFile array, are empty. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Not really... You need to step through the code with the debugger and find out the value of `c` before the line in your code that gives you the error.

Comment: Ok, now I've understood. Give me a moment!

Comment: Expression c, Value <No Variables>, Type Variant/Object

Comment: OK, so since `c` appears to have nothing in it, then I suspect the way you populate the values/ranges in the array has failed in some way. You will probably need to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for people to be able to reproduce the problem independently. At the moment, only you know how that array gets populated.

Comment: I don't understand, It seems that the variable is cleared, because in the loop before it did have a value.

Answer (score 0):

As the items named `RawHg202Range` etc are actually `Range` objects then you should use `Is Nothing` to check if they are empty:

```
AddressRawDataFile = Array(RawHg202Range, RawPb204Range, RawPb206Range, RawPb207Range, RawPb208Range, RawTh232Range, RawU238Range, _
    RawHg202Header, RawPb204HeaderRange, RawPb206HeaderRange, RawPb207HeaderRange, RawPb208HeaderRange, RawTh232HeaderRange, _
    RawU238HeaderRange)

    For Each c In AddressRawDataFile
        If c Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: But, until I get this error, my code is doing exactly what I want. Can you explain why I should use the "Is Nothing"? What is the advantage? I am testing my code using your suggestion.

Comment: `= ""` is a comparison that only works for Strings. In the same way, you would expect `= 0` to only work for numbers. For object types, you either have an object or you don't and, in the case where you don't have a reference to an object, VBA uses the special value `Nothing` to show this. This value can't be tested with `=` but is instead tested with `Is`. Therefore, `c Is Nothing` means: if this particular `c` is not associated with any object

Comment: barrowc, your suggestion is not working correctly. Even if the cell indicated by the range is empty, my if structure fails to indicate this using the "If c Is Nothing Then".

Comment: I understand, but I am not testing if my variables were set to some object, I'd like to see if the cells indicated by these ranges are not empty. Some information must be written there.

Comment: Show some of the code which populates the variables so we can try and understand what they are actually pointing to. Also, the variable called `RawHg202Header` is named differently to all the rest (all the others end in `HeaderRange` and not just `Header`) - this isn't necessarily a problem though

Comment: Actually barrowc, that's exactly the point!! The correct variable is RawHg202HeaderRange! RawHg202Header is a reference to a refedit which I use to populate the cell indicated by RawHg202HeaderRange. Just a little mistake that cost a lot of time and efforts! I will make more tests, but I thinks this was the problem. Thank you guys for the patience and attention!!!

Comment: Hard to tell without more info. To avoid similar issues in future, try putting `Option Explicit` at the top of each module so the compiler catches wrongly named variables (or you can check the "Require variable declaration" box in Tools > Options in the Visual Basic editor and every module you create will start with `Option Explicit)`

Comment: Actually, both variables are defined, the problem was calling one when I needed the other one, but thanks for the tip!